# Extract a Json from a bigger JSON in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a JSON object which is in this form :

```
[
{
    "id": "458712e247328e4ebfafeb4d922b",
    "value": [
        1
    ],
    "location": null,
    "metadata": null,
    "at": "2015-07-16T16:33:39.113Z"
},
{
    "id": "1ghj78d8220734c00ab941f91b14e334b",
    "value": [
        100
    ],
    "location": null,
    "metadata": null,
    "at": "2015-07-16T16:33:26.819Z"
}
]
```

I want to extract the "value" (which equals 100 here ) from the FIRST one (and only this one).
How can I do that in node.js?

Or am I obliged to convert this JSON to a string and to manipulate it? (with substring for example).

Thank you

Comment: parse the json, then just `arr[1]['value']`. don't use string operations on json...

Comment: try the below code and do let me know if it works for your problem,

Comment: I wish people would stop calling json strings objects and vice-versa. so confusing. and even worse, json objects....

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question title should be "How can extract a value from an object".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert json to normal javascript object and then you can use dot notation to manipulate our json and then again convert the resulting javascript object to json.

```
var jsonObj = [
{
    "id": "458712e247328e4ebfafeb4d922b",
    "value": [
        1
    ],
    "location": null,
    "metadata": null,
    "at": "2015-07-16T16:33:39.113Z"
},
{
    "id": "1ghj78d8220734c00ab941f91b14e334b",
    "value": [
        100
    ],
    "location": null,
    "metadata": null,
    "at": "2015-07-16T16:33:26.819Z"
}
];
var jsObj = JSON.parse(jsonObj);

var resulJsonObj = JSON.stringify(jsObj[1].value);
```

In case you just need the value as it is :

```
var value= jsObj[1].value;
```

Comment: Any reason why you're stringifying the value?

Comment: to convert the javascript object back to json

Comment: Why do you want to do that? The question doesn't ask for it.

Comment: ok my bad I though you need the value back in json, See the edited answer then

Answer (score 0):

As Marc B. pointed out, using string operations on JSON is kind of a waste, since JSON already provides you with easy access to the stored data. I'm including an example so you can see how easy it is to access the value you are looking for.

```js
    var data = [{
      "id": "458712e247328e4ebfafeb4d922b",
      "value": [ 1 ],
      "location": null,
      "metadata": null,
      "at": "2015-07-16T16:33:39.113Z"
    }, {
      "id": "1ghj78d8220734c00ab941f91b14e334b",
      "value": [ 100 ],
      "location": null,
      "metadata": null,
      "at": "2015-07-16T16:33:26.819Z"
    }];

    var el = document.getElementById("target");
    el.innerHTML = data[1].value;
```

```html
<p>Value: <span id="target"></span>
</p>
```